# Where is the documentation for Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions?

Tags: webpack, asp.net-core-mvc

This [official Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0) says `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices` are obsolete and "A simpler SPA frameworks integration mechanism is available" in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions`.

I can't find any documentation at all for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions`. There doesn't seem to be a corresponding namespace so I can't even find anything using IntelliSense.

The [obsolescence announcement on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12890) is similarly vague.

Specifically, I'm trying to find out how to upgrade a call to `app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware`.

Where is the official documentation for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions`?

Comment: Not too encouraging news but maybe [this](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/18405#issuecomment-760546008) is helpful.

Comment: One of the original intentions for having the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices was to integrate Angular development into Visual Studio with it's add-in. As the versions of Angular, Node.js and .NET Core changed so rapidly over the past two years most developers (like myself) have found it quite challenging and frustrating to keep up with the various versions of these dependencies without having the projects break whenever something gets upgraded such as one of the Node packages. My preference now is to develop SPA apps separately from the Web API and manage upgrades on each side separately.

Comment: @AndrewHalil I'd agree - I think the functionality provided was motivated by making an easy one-click VS template but there's too much behind-the-scenes "magic" and no explanation of how it works. Having said that, after throwing away the react part of the sample and replacing it with my own react project, I have done a few platform upgrades on both sides and nothing broke, but my project is still only a year old.

Comment: Regarding Jeanne's post - I've found this video helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DH2yUVQDB0I&t=1975s

Comment: there is more discussion on this issue here https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/18405

Comment: There is another totally different approach you can use. What the Microsoft solution does is start the webpack dev server then configure the ASP.NET server to proxy any routes not handled by your ASP.NET code into that. However you can do it the other way round - start the webpack dev server yourself and configure it to proxy the API routes into the ASP.NET server. Then you don't have to use any of those MS libraries.

Comment: Not that it helps with your problem, but for ease of reference regarding your concern that, "There doesn't seem to be a corresponding namespace [for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions`] so I can't even find anything using IntelliSense.", the [NuGet package is here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions) and is currently built [from the source here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/ae1a6cbe225b99c0bf38b7e31bf60cb653b73a52/src/Middleware/Spa/SpaServices.Extensions).

Comment: Check the links below https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.spaservices.spaoptions?view=aspnetcore-6.0 this might be useful to https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions

Comment: Please note that this question is on-topic because [it is asking for an objective answer related to documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386006/2370483). It should not be closed for asking for resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some of the docs that may help, however they are not very detailed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.spaservices?view=aspnetcore-6.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices Namespace Provides types for hosting
> a Single Page Application (SPA).
>
> SpaOptions Describes options for hosting a Single
> Page Application (SPA).
>
> ISpaBuilder Defines a class that provides
> mechanisms for configuring the hosting of a Single Page Application
> (SPA) and attaching middleware.

Comment: This does indeed seem to be new documentation added since I asked the original question. The app I was working on was .Net 3.1 and is no longer being maintained, but hopefully this is at least a start for those trying to use this functionality now

Comment: Thanks @Andy, I don't know when it was added by yes, Microsoft needs better documentations of their new features.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're asking specifically about upgrading the call to `app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware()`, I found that [this NuGet package](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore/issues/12890#issuecomment-784537371) does exactly that!